# How to start new page after login

Tags: android, authentication

I'm really struggling with this app i'm making, its my first time programming android. I'm trying to have a login page using sqlite with a registration page if not registered, to then go to a new page if successful. All that happens so far is I can see my login page.

**Login Activity**

```
`package com.stu54259.moneymanager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.stu54259.moneymanager.R;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import Database.DatabaseManager;

public class LoginFragment extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buttonLogin;
    DatabaseManager mDatabaseManager;
    EditText editTextEmail;
    EditText editTextPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);
        mDatabaseManager = new DatabaseManager(this);
        initViews();

        //set click event of login button
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Check user input is correct or not
                if (validate()) {

                    //Get values from EditText fields
                    String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                    String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                    //Authenticate user
                    User currentUser = mDatabaseManager.Authenticate(new User(null, null, Email, Password));

                    //Check Authentication is successful or not
                    if (currentUser != null) {
                        Snackbar.make(buttonLogin, "Successfully Logged in!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //User Logged in Successfully Launch You home screen activity

                        Intent intent=new Intent(LoginFragment.this,HomeFragment.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {

                        //User Logged in Failed
                        Snackbar.make(buttonLogin, "Failed to log in , please try again", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            }
        });




 }



    //this method is used to connect XML views to its Objects
    private void initViews() {
        editTextEmail = (EditText) editTextEmail.findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) editTextPassword.findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        buttonLogin = (Button) buttonLogin.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    }

    //This method is for handling fromHtml method deprecation
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static Spanned fromHtml(String html) {
        Spanned result;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            result = Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            result = Html.fromHtml(html);
        }
        return result;
    }

    //This method is used to validate input given by user
    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = false;

        //Get values from EditText fields
        String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
        String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        //Handling validation for Email field
        if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()) {
            valid = false;
            editTextEmail.setError("Please enter valid email!");
        } else {
            valid = true;
            editTextEmail.setError(null);
        }

        //Handling validation for Password field
        if (Password.isEmpty()) {
            valid = false;
            editTextPassword.setError("Please enter valid password!");
        } else {
            if (Password.length() > 5) {
                valid = true;
                editTextPassword.setError(null);
            } else {
                valid = false;
                editTextPassword.setError("Password is to short!");
            }
        }

        return valid;
    }

}`

**Register activity**

package com.stu54259.moneymanager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

import Database.DatabaseManager;

public class RegisterFragment extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Declaration EditTexts
    EditText editTextUserName;
    EditText editTextEmail;
    EditText editTextPassword;

    //Declaration TextInputLayout
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutUserName;
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutEmail;
    TextInputLayout textInputLayoutPassword;

    //Declaration Button
    Button buttonRegister;

    //Declaration SqliteHelper
    DatabaseManager mDatabaseManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_register);
        mDatabaseManager = new DatabaseManager(this);
        initTextViewLogin();
        initViews();
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (validate()) {
                    String UserName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                    String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
                    String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                    //Check in the database is there any user associated with  this email
                    if (!mDatabaseManager.isEmailExists(Email)) {

                        //Email does not exist now add new user to database
                        mDatabaseManager.addUser(new User(null, UserName, Email, Password));
                        Snackbar.make(buttonRegister, "User created successfully! Please Login ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        new Handler() {
                            public void postDelayed(Runnable runnable, int lengthLong) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void publish(LogRecord record) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void flush() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void close() throws SecurityException {

                            }
                        }.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                finish();
                            }
                        }, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }else {

                        //Email exists with email input provided so show error user already exist
                        Snackbar.make(buttonRegister, "User already exists with same email ", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            }
        });
    }

    //this method used to set Login TextView click event
    private void initTextViewLogin() {
        TextView textViewLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login);
        textViewLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    //this method is used to connect XML views to its Objects
    private void initViews() {
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);

        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);

        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

    }

    //This method is used to validate input given by user
    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = false;

        //Get values from EditText fields
        String UserName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
        String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        //Handling validation for UserName field
        if (UserName.isEmpty()) {
            valid = false;
            textInputLayoutUserName.setError("Please enter valid username!");
        } else {
            if (UserName.length() > 5) {
                valid = true;
                textInputLayoutUserName.setError(null);
            } else {
                valid = false;
                textInputLayoutUserName.setError("Username is to short!");
            }
        }

        //Handling validation for Email field
        if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()) {
            valid = false;
            textInputLayoutEmail.setError("Please enter valid email!");
        } else {
            valid = true;
            textInputLayoutEmail.setError(null);
        }

        //Handling validation for Password field
        if (Password.isEmpty()) {
            valid = false;
            textInputLayoutPassword.setError("Please enter valid password!");
        } else {
            if (Password.length() > 5) {
                valid = true;
                textInputLayoutPassword.setError(null);
            } else {
                valid = false;
                textInputLayoutPassword.setError("Password is to short!");
            }
        }


        return valid;
    }
}

**Login XML**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/tv_subtitle"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/et_email"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/tag"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/et_password"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/et_password"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/toRegister"
        android:textSize="15sp" />



</RelativeLayout>

**Register XML**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".RegisterFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/tag"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/your_name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_repassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/re_type_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="@string/register"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="@string/click_to_login"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you, please help.

Comment: You have to add your second activity in `manifest.xml` file .

Comment: could you please tell us from which activity to which are you trying to traverse to?

Comment: To HomeFragment, there is nothing on that page yet just want the operation to work first.